# Jenkins: Installed Jenkins on Linux host successfully but unable to reach thru URL

Tags: jenkins

I am having issues accessing Jenkins via URL.

Jenkins installed on Linux host successfully 
When tried via URL http://hostname:8080, got below error

```
<SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="urn:nsrvmws1" xmlns:ns2="urn:nsrvmws2">
<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>HTTP GET method not implemented</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

Please help me out.

Ps: on other servers, I'm able to install and access without any issues, but those servers are assigned to other resources.

Comment: We'll need a lot more information. Are you running this directly on the server? Are you sure Jenkins is running on port 8080? How are you trying to access the server? That doesn't look like a browser error.

Comment: I'm wondering if that server might already have something running on port 8080? What do you get when you execute the following? lsof -i tcp:8080

Answer (score 0):

Hit using 
http://IP Address :8080  in browser
I think it should work if you accessing via other computer.